# Having issues making requests to an API using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, express

My company uses the software nocrm.io to keep track of leads and customers.  I would like to use their API within our web application to be able to GET and POST information.  Currently I'm having issues with trying to make http requests within our web application using their API.  Every time I try and do a GET request to ping my APIKey I get back a 401 error.  I've tried making requests via Postman and they work, but when I try and implement these requests within my application they don't, which makes things a bit frustrating.

If anyone has had any experience using this API or something similar that could help me, that would be great.

Here is the link to their API: https://youdontneedacrm.com/api#nocrm.io-api

Currently I'm using jquery AJAX to make the requests.  I've tried putting the APIKey in the headers like their API suggests, but this just gives me 401 and CORS.  Their API also suggests that you can put the APIKey within the parameters of the request but I still get the same 401 error.

Yes, I have also made sure that the APIKey I'm using is correct so that shouldn't be the issue.

I put the request in the browser which returns a 200 status saying that my APIKey is correct as well.

Below is what is currently giving me 401 errors.

myfile.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'
const api_key = require('../../../env.config.json').CRM.API_KEY;

class Myfile extends React.Component{

 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {}
 }

    PingApi(){
        var url = 'https://OUR_ACCOUNT.nocrm.io/api/v2/ping'
        var apikey = api_key

        var dataObject = {
            'X-API-KEY': apikey
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: url,
            data: dataObject,
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log("Good");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        })
    }


 render(){
  return(
   <button onClick={this.PingApi.bind(this)}>Ping API</button>
  );
 }
}

export default Myfile
```

I expected to get a 200 status with a json object returned, but instead got 401.

**EDIT**
Here is a screenshot of the request working in Postman.  Obviously I blocked out the sensitive information for security reasons.  And yes the API key is the same as the one I am using in our web app.

[image]

Comment: Did you log the api key and check if it is correct?

Comment: @Keerthi yes I logged the api key and they are exactly the same.

Comment: Did you try to call api with axios?  We generally use axios in reactjs to call api.

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes I have tried using axios but it gives me CORS issues, Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Preflight errors.  AJAX seemed to be the only one that kind of bypassed these issues.

Comment: can you post a postman screenshot? (as you said it works)

Comment: Seems like the API key would be in the header and not in the body

Comment: `headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "X-API-KEY": apikey}`

Comment: @iLiA I edited the post to contain the Postman screenshot.

Comment: @tymeJV in the api docs, it says it also possible to send api key in request body.

 The preferred way to send us the api key or the user token is through the header of the request. However, if it is easier for you, instead of passing the api key or user token in the header you can add it as parameter of the request.

Comment: @SuleymanSah - yep, but OP's request is a GET, there is no request body.

Comment: you are sending data in ajax with `data:` and i am not an ajax expert but it is probably getting data as `.body.api_key` and not as header

Comment: @tymeJV answer is what you need

Answer (score 1):

While you can pass the API key thru the request body or the headers (according to the docs) - you're sending a GET request, where there is no body. Pass it thru the header:

```
headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "X-API-KEY": apikey}
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that now I get CORS Preflight errors.  This is because we are adding custom headers, and we all know that CORS doesn't like custom headers.